# Auto detect resolution of preview pin - Directshow

Tags: c++, windows, directshow, resolution, detection

I have a graph that displays the preview of a capture card (AVerMedia HD DVR PCI) to a window that is connected to a ps3 via components. I would like to know if there is a simple way of detecting when the resolution of the source changes.

For example, for ps3, the menu is displayed at 1920X1080 (1080i) and when you enter a game, the game changes to 1280X720 (720p). I would like to set the resolution using IAMStreamConfig and AM_MEDIA_TYPE but I need to know when to switch the resolution. If it were to stay at 1080i, the image would be 1/4 of the entire rectangle showing a bad experience.

Would a solution be creating a filter and reading the bytes of the image to detect if there is data there?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is no standard detection, you need to either check with video input hardware vendor/SDK, or otherwise look for graph events if you happen to receive anything relevant with resolution change. Resolution change is important but the API and its design come from times when it was a second priority thing.

Comment: Where would I find the graph event? WM_GRAPHNOTIFY?

Comment: Yes, you can also see it interactively on GraphStudio or GraphStudioNext.

Comment: Oh I probably see an event in GraphStudio. It triggers after I manually change the resolution of the capture/preview pin, would it trigger if the ps3 automatically changes its resolution so I can change it in the graph?